# como guardar una fecha dd/mm/yyyy en base de datos

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos

hola amigos como estan ? tengo un inconveniente con un cod que estoy realizando al guardar en la base de datos y es el siguiente

```
$fechanac= $_POST ['fechanac'];



  $fechaservidor = date('Y-M-D'); 
$fechaactual = date("D-M-Y", strtotime($fecha_nac));


$results=$bd->query("INSERT INTO bodas (
                    
                    fecha_nac
                    ) 
                VALUES
                 (  '$fechaactual'
                )");
```

es que cuando registro me aparece es de esta manera **Sun-Oct-1980** y no asi **12/10/1980**  el campo de **fechanac** en la bd lo guarde como campo tipo **varchar**

Comment: Y si guardas eso en un campo date, datetime, timestamp o algo similar que haya en la BD que estés usando? Operar sobre esa fecha va a ser mucho más fácil que guardando un varchar con formato...

Comment: me aparece de esta manera ... 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Usa la clase Carbon de PHP, con ella podrás dar el formato que quieres al momento de imprimir las fechas y no te importaría como esta sea guardada en la base de datos.

Comment: @kevinrueda Carbon no es una clase de PHP, se construye a partir de la clase DateTime que si es propia de PHP: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ creo que es importante aclarar ese punto (*para que el OP asimile que si desea incluirla deberá instalarla por separado en su proyecto*), por otro lado novato creo que sería mas simple si la almacenas como un tipo DATE y cuando la requieras solo la formateas sea desde MySQL o desde PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondiendo tu pregunta tendrías que guardarlo así:

```
$fechaactual = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha_nac));
```

Puedes ver más información en https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Pero te recomiendo guardar las fechas en date/datetime, para guardar en datetime al menos en MySql tendrías que hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$fechaactual = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($fecha_nac));
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvio